# python: create a new dataframe with specific column using pandas

Tags: python

```
def csv_reader(fileName):
    usecols=['_id__$oid','payload','channel']
    io = pd.read_csv(fileName,sep=",",names=usecols)
    df = pd.DataFrame(io,columns=['_id__$oid','payload','channel'])
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('trimmed.csv')

if __name__=="__main__":
    csv_path = "snort_alerts.csv"
    csv_reader(csv_path)
```

Using pandas for python for the first time.

I am trying to extract 3 columns from a dataset based on the column names and write it back to another csv using pandas. The dataframe **io** contains all the columns instead of just the columns specified **usecols**, I even tried doing the same by specifying the column numbers.Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: You can use `rename`: `df.rename(columns={'old_name': 'new_name'}, inplace=True)`

Comment: You use `names` incorrectly. In `pd.read_csv`, replace `names=usecols` with `usecols=usecols`.

Answer (score -1):

is this what you are looking for ?

```
xcolumns = ['_id__$oid','payload','channel']

io[xcolumns]
```

despite the minus vote, I think that this is is what the user is looking for

```
io = pd.read_csv("snort_alerts.csv",sep=",")
df = io[['_id__$oid','payload','channel']]
```